# How to output a comparison of values in separate files

Tags: shell, sed, awk

With the following two files available with build names and version numbers available:

**server.txt**

```
Build2 200
Build3 100
Build1 400
Build7 200
```

**local.txt**

```
Build1 300
Build2 200
Build3 100
```

In my situation, the two lists aren't necessarily in order or have the same number of values.

A build is "Updated" if the local value is the same as the server value.
How can I create an output that displays whether the output is "Updated" or "Out-of-date", like the example below:

```
Build2 Updated
Build3 Updated
Build1 Out-of-date
Build7 Out-of-date
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical solution with `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { k[$1] = $2; next }
  { print $1, (k[$1] == $2) ? "Updated" : "Out-of-date" }
' local.txt server.txt
```